# JWT request can't go through Authorize policy

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing JWT Authorization on Asp.Net but I am having a trouble here. When I am trying to access the Dashboard/Home controller's method I am always recieving '401 Unauthorized' response. According to my research I can say that the request can not go through

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]
```

But when comment that statement I recieve an error here

```
var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
```

Which states that sequence conatains no appropriate elements, and if I will print the

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims
```

I basically recieve a '[]'.
Also I want you to notice that the token is 
[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW0kK.png)
I am testing the application with help of [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10qc.png)
I stacked on this error for two days and really rely on your help. Tell me if some additional code is needed.
Code:
Dashboard Controller:

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "ApiUser")]
        [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
        public class DashboardController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _caller;
            private readonly BackendContext _appDbContext;
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

            public DashboardController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, BackendContext appDbContext, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            {
                _caller = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
                _appDbContext = appDbContext;
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }

            // GET api/dashboard/home

            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Home()
            {
                // retrieve the user info
                //HttpContext.User
                //return new OkObjectResult(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims);
                    var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");

                var customer = await _appDbContext.Customers.Include(c => c.Identity).SingleAsync(c => c.Identity.Id == userId.Value);

                return new OkObjectResult(new
                {
                    Message = "This is secure API and user data!",
                    customer.Identity.FirstName,
                    customer.Identity.LastName,
                    customer.Identity.PictureUrl,
                    customer.Identity.FacebookId,
                    customer.Location,
                    customer.Locale,
                    customer.Gender
                });
            }
        }
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup
    {
        private const string SecretKey = "iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH"; // todo: get this from somewhere secure
        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey));

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BackendContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddDbContext<BackendContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                  b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Backend")));

            services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();
            var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

            // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
            services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
                options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            });

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
            {
                configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
                configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
            });

            // api user claim policy
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
            });

            // add identity
            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
            {
                // configure identity options
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            });
            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<BackendContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
            services.AddDbContext<BackendContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Backend")));
            services.AddTransient<IStoreService, StoreService>();
            services.AddMvc();//.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Constants (used in startup):

```
 public static class Constants
        {
            public static class Strings
            {
                public static class JwtClaimIdentifiers
                {
                    public const string Rol = "rol", Id = "id";
                }

                public static class JwtClaims
                {
                    public const string ApiAccess = "api_access";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue is caused by the mismatch configuration between token generation and validation for `Issuer` and `Audience`.

In `Startup.cs`, you configure `ValidateIssuer = true` and `ValidateAudience = true`, but for your provided token, there is no `iss` and `aud`.

Here are two ways for a try:

- Disable to validate `Issuer` and `Audience`

  ```
      var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateIssuer = false,
          ValidIssuer = "Issuer",

          ValidateAudience = false,
          ValidAudience = "Audience",

          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
          IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

          RequireExpirationTime = false,
          ValidateLifetime = true,
          ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
      };
  ```
- Or, provide the `Issuer` and `Audience` while generating the token.

  ```
      public IActionResult Login()
  {
      var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("iNivDmHLpUA223sqsfhqGbMRdRj1PVkH"));
      var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

      var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
          issuer: "Issuer",
          audience: "Audience",
          claims: new List<Claim>() { new Claim("rol", "api_access") },
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(25),
          signingCredentials: signinCredentials
      );

      var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
      return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
  }
  ```

Here is a working demo [CoreJwt](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/Security/CoreJwt).

Answer (score 0):

It has passed about 4 months since this question has been asked, but I hope it will help the future visitors, I had the same problem and it was because I had missed to add the `app.UseAuthentication();` to my `Configure` method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
//////////////////////////
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Also I had missed to add the `JwtIssuerOptions` to my `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`:

```
"JwtIssuerOptions": {
"Issuer": "webApi",
"Audience": "http://localhost:5000/"
},
```